# gitlab webhook for teamcity build based on commit change

Tags: gitlab, teamcity, webhooks

can i have a sample gitlab webhook which can hit the teamcity,each time a commit change occurs.  http://teamcity.int:8080/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/commitHookNotification?locator=vcsRoot:(id:$vcsrootId) but hitting a 401 :
Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 401 Authentication required To login manually go to "/login.html" page

has added the access token created in teamcity for the webhook authetication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put teamcity login and token in url:

```
http://username:token@teamcity.localdomain/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/commitHookNotification?locator=vcsRoot:(id:$TEAMCITY_VCS_ID)
```